# Однородные или неоднородные приложения - автор, художник, писатель?

Tags: части-речи

Автор книги американский художник и писатель Арт Шпигельман рассказывает о жизни еврейской семьи во время Второй мировой войны, основанной на жизни отца писателя – польского еврея, выжившего в Холокосте и переехавшего в США.

Автор, художник, писатель - это однородные или неоднородные приложения? И соответственно надо ставить запятые между ними или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Приложения неоднородные, обозначают разные признаки, не разделяются запятыми.

Сравнить:

Мой друг писатель Васильев   жил тогда в Москве.

Мой друг художник и поэт в дождливый вечер на стекле мою любовь нарисовал, открыв мне чудо на земле.